# Dagger 2, Dependency injection

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

Anyone knows how does Dagger 2 work? A little tutorial for beginners.
I dont understand how to works the Components and providers and the named tags? ...

Thanks for your answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide: Inside modules we define methods containing this annotation which tells Dagger how we want to construct and provide those mentioned dependencies.

Component: Components basically are injectors, let’s say a bridge between

Inject and Module, which its main responsibility is to put both together. They just give you instances of all the types you defined, for example, we must annotate an interface with Component and list all the Modules that will compose that component, and if any of them is missing, we get errors at compile time. All the components are aware of the scope of dependencies it provides through its modules.

Try this tutorial: 
http://aluxion.com/blog/dagger-2-inyeccion-de-dependencias-en-android/

It is in Spanish and very useful